# Hartl RoR Chap. 9.3.1 spec test failure

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I seem to be running into failures left and right... i checked my code, and everything is defined and spell check is in check... Here are my failures...:

```
Failures:

  1) User pages index should list each user
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `each'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages index 
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `each'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages index 
     Failure/Error: visit users_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `each'
     # ./app/views/users/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___3453469340594189774_70210782785680'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.87 seconds
70 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages index should list each user
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16 # User pages index 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:15 # User pages index
```

here is my code:
spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do
    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

    it "should list each user" do
      User.all.each do |user|
        page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end

        it "should create a user" do
         expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [ :index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

      it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }


      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end
      end

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

sussions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

What is wrong here?? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You need this code from listing 7.29. It's for editing the gavatars.

> Listing 7.29. Defining an optional :size parameter for the
>   gravatar_for helper.
>
> app/helpers/users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user_pages spec has these lines which don't match

```
describe "index" do
    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end
```

Chapter 9.3 doesn't have the Bob email etc